# PHP Print array values without all the extra "=>" stuff

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I want to simply print out a list of all the values. Not sure why I can't find the answer to this. I have tried "var_dump" and "Var_export", "TRUE" and "FALSE". Here is my code:

```
$var = var_export($xyz,TRUE);
print "$var";
```

But it outputs this:

```
array (
  0 => '700',
  1 => '750', etc
```

I just want this:

```
700
750
```

Comment: You're generating code here. You don't have full control over what the result will look like. All you can expect is that it *works* the same. And it does. Why do you care?

Comment: How about looping through the array and printing each element individually?

Comment: There is no direct mechanism to print array values as you wished. you may need to go for a loop. Also you can use  <pre> tag to intend the output in a easy readable manner. Eg echo "<pre>".print_r($var,1)."</pre>"

Comment: `print implode("\n", $array)` will print each item separated by a new-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $a = array (700, 750);
    foreach($a as $key => $value)
    {
      echo $value. "<br>";
    }
?>
```

You can easily print the value of an array using the foreach loop. Here I gave an example for your better help.

Comment: No request for HTML in the question.

Comment: You aren't using the key so you could reduce that to `foreach($a as $value)`, which would make this a dupe answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54865516/3392762

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($xyz as $val) {
    echo $val . '<br>'; 
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iterating into $xyz using a foreach loop ?

```
foreach($xyz as $value) {
print "$value \n" }
```

The \n being a new line.

edit : identical to @PHPNoob's answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are attempting to get the values from an array.
Using a Foreach will loop through the array apply the code to each value until the array is complete.

```
foreach($xyz as $value){
    echo $value . "<br/>";
}
```